# Is Invoking for thread safe winform manipulation a performance hungry action? And is it really necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, thread-safety

After reactivating the illegal cross thread call check in my heavily parallelized C# winforms software (CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls) I got tons of debug exceptions about those unsafe calls.

For example lines like:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
```

throws an exception.

To "fix" those one liners I simply used invoke from the class instance that created/owns the flowlayoutpanel, like this:

```
ownerClassInstance.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear(); });
```

Now I have the following questions

1) Couldn't I just use CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls and stop worrying? I haven't had a single problem because of thread unsafe actions. To be honest I don't even know any real world examples where thread unsafe winforms programming would lead to unpredictable behavior. I am just afraid I will stumble upon true problems later and try to keep things clean from the start.

2) Does it cost much performance to "wrap" lines with this invokement of a casted delegate (lambda?)? Like if I add 1000 objects to a flowlayoutpanel, does it get measurably and noticeably slower if those add method calls are made threadsafe the way I do it?

Comment: No; WinForms itself is not thread-safe.

Comment: You should run as much as possible in each lambda and have fewer `Invoke()`s.

Comment: I'd like to keep changes to the code flow to a minimum. Every change of my winform element is where it's logically supposed to be. I do not want to call methodInvokers in class A from class B, it makes it harder to understand for those who come after me.

Comment: @traubenfuchs I think you're looking for `Async / Await`.